# SQL - Running Select Query with Having Clause

Tags: sql

here is the query I want to run.

```
SELECT COUNT(tableA.ID)
FROM tableA
NATURAL JOIN tableB
NATURAL JOIN tableC
WHERE tableB.Time IS NULL
GROUP BY tableA.ID
HAVING COUNT(tableA.ID) < tableC.Quantity
```

This query will run perfectly fine **without** the `HAVING` clause, however the `HAVING` clause has an error which I can't pick out.

The purpose of the `HAVING` clause is that I want to return `ID's` that have less than the Quantity threshold (which is defined as `tableC.Quantity`).

How can I fix my current `HAVING` clause to incorporate that the query only returns `ID's` that are less than the `tableC.Quantity`.

Note: if you need more clarification, I can provide more.

Comment: You said that you want to return `ID's` that have less than the Quantity threshold, but you're not selecting `ID's`, you're selecting a `COUNT` of them.  What do you want exactly - a count, or the individual ID's?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the COUNT of ID's that are less than the quantity threshold for that ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that the error is something to the effect that `tableC.quantity` is not in the `group by` clause (and that you are not using MySQL).  If so, you can fix this by using an aggregation function:

```
SELECT COUNT(tableA.ID)
FROM tableA NATURAL JOIN
     tableB NATURAL JOIN
     tableC
WHERE tableB.Time IS NULL
GROUP BY tableA.ID
HAVING COUNT(tableA.ID) < max(tableC.Quantity);
```

By the way, I think `natural join` is a dangerous operation.  You could add a new column to a table and invalidate all your queries, with no error message to tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: You and OP are definitely going to want to select the actual tableA.ID as well, or the counts will be kind of meaningless (well, unless there's only 1 row in result).

Comment: Ahh this works. I don't know why max(tableC.Quantity) works and not tableC.Quantity, but it works. Thank you.

Comment: @Gerrat Thank you for the advice but I have my reasons, thank you though.